# Angular2 reactive form, read value from list of radio-buttons and text-boxes

Tags: angular, dynamic-forms, angular-reactive-forms

I have dynamically created form, i followed tutorial from angular2 cookbook for dynamic forms: [Tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dynamic-form.html). I created there my custom  dynamic control "RadioTextboxField", which contains list of radio-buttons, and optionally each radio-button can have associated textbox control.

**Base class:**

```
export class QuestionBase<T>{
value: T;
key: string;
label: string;
required: boolean;
order: number;
controlType: string;

constructor(options: {
  value?: T,
  key?: string,
  label?: string,
  required?: boolean,
  order?: number,
  controlType?: string
  } = {}) 

 {
   this.value = options.value;
   this.key = options.key || '';
   this.label = options.label || '';
   this.required = !!options.required;
   this.order = options.order === undefined ? 1 : options.order;
   this.controlType = options.controlType || '';
  }
}
```

**RadioTexboxField:**

```
import { QuestionBase } from './question-base';

export class RadioTextboxField extends QuestionBase<string> {
controlType = 'textbox-radio';
labelRadio: { label: string, isTextBox: boolean, value:any }[] = [];
radioVal:string;

 constructor(options: {} = {}) {
     super(options);
     this.labelRadio = options['labelRadio'] || '';
     this.radioVal = options['radioVal'] || '';
  }
}
```

where **labelRadio:** list of radio-buttons and optional textboxes which are included in control 
( **label:** label displayed next to radio-button,
 **isTextBox:** specified if textbox is displayed, 
**value:** specified value for radio-button if textbox isn't visible, otherwise value from textbox should be taken).
Here is my form:
**Form:**

```
<div [formGroup]="form">
  <label [attr.for]="question.key">{{question.label}}</label>
   <div [ngSwitch]="question.controlType">

   <input *ngSwitchCase="'textbox'" [formControlName]="question.key"
        [id]="question.key" [type]="question.type">

   <select [id]="question.key" *ngSwitchCase="'dropdown'" 
    [formControlName]="question.key">
    <option *ngFor="let opt of question.options" [value]="opt.key">
    {{opt.value}}</option>
    </select>

    <div *ngSwitchCase="'textbox-radio'">
      <div *ngFor="let opts of question.labelRadio; let j=index">

      <!--  my radio-button control !-->
      <input type="radio" [id]="question.key" [value]="opts.value" (click)="question.radioVal=opts.value;" [checked]="question.radioVal==opts.value">     
       <label [attr.for]="question.key" >{{opts.label}}</label>
       <input [id]="'text'+j" *ngIf="opts.isTextBox"
        [type]="text" class="form-control input-sm" [readonly]="question.radioVal!=opts.value" [formControlName]="question.key" [value]="opts.isTextBox ? question.key : opts.value">
     </div>
</div> 
<div class="errorMessage" *ngIf="!isValid">{{question.label}} is 
required</div>
```

I have problem to read value from that control, to get value from radio-button or optionally from textbox if it's displayed. I would like to also disable the textboxes if associated to it radio-button isn't check. Here is link to full code on plunker: [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/IpPQ5Pk3KT17X4nU3O8I?p=preview)
Please help me, I have no idea how to solve this.